# Highlight active menu item in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm overriding the mod_mainmenu module in Joomla 1.5 and am unable to get the `.active` or `#current` CSS class or ID to show on the page. It's showing the following HTML for the menu:

```
<ul id="top-nav" class="flatList">
  <li access="0" level="1" id="1">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="embed embed-top-nav">Home</span>
      <p>news, highlights</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li access="0" level="1" id="4">
    <a href="/content/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=1&amp;Itemid=4">
      <span class="embed embed-top-nav">Watch UNC-TV</span>
      <p>schedule, programs</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've read that the mod_mainmenu will automatically insert either `active` or `current` somewhere into this so you can tell which item is the currently active menu selection. But I'm not seeing either of those in the generated HTML. I'd like to apply some CSS to the active element, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do this. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Here's the code of the mod_mainmenu I've created:

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

if ( ! defined('fancyMenuPatch') ) 
{
  function fancyMenuPatch($result,$tag){
    $menu   = JSite::getMenu();
    $active = $menu->getActive();

    // Add to the start of the UL tag.
    $begin_ul = "<ul id=\"top-nav\" class=\"flatList\">";
    $begin_span = "<span class=\"embed embed-top-nav\">";

    $home_p = "Home</span><p>news, highlights</p></a>";
    $watch_p = "Watch UNC-TV</span><p>schedule, programs</p></a>";
    $learn_p = "Learn</span><p>education, unc-tv kids</p></a>";
    $support_p = "Support Us</span><p>pledge, volunteer, corporate</p></a>";
    $contact_p = "Contact</span><p>feedback, connect, share</p></a>";

    // do the replacements
    $result = str_replace("<ul class=\"menu\">",$begin_ul, $result);
    $result = str_replace("<span>", $begin_span, $result);
    $result = str_replace("Home</span></a>",$home_p,$result);
    $result = str_replace("Watch UNC-TV</span></a>",$watch_p,$result);
    $result = str_replace("Learn</span></a>",$learn_p,$result);
    $result = str_replace("Support Us</span></a>",$support_p,$result);
    $result = str_replace("Contact</span></a>",$contact_p,$result);

    return $result;
  }
  define('fancyMenuPatch', true);
}

if ( ! defined('modMainMenuXMLCallbackDefined') )
{
function modMainMenuXMLCallback(&$node, $args)
{
  $user = &JFactory::getUser();
  $menu = &JSite::getMenu();
  $active   = $menu->getActive();
  $path = isset($active) ? array_reverse($active->tree) : null;

  if (($args['end']) && ($node->attributes('level') >= $args['end']))
  {
    $children = $node->children();
    foreach ($node->children() as $child)
    {
      if ($child->name() == 'ul') {
        $node->removeChild($child);
      }
    }
  }

  if ($node->name() == 'ul') {
    foreach ($node->children() as $child)
    {
      if ($child->attributes('access') > $user->get('aid', 0)) {
        $node->removeChild($child);
      }
    }
  }

  if (($node->name() == 'li') && isset($node->ul)) {
    $node->addAttribute('class', 'parent');
  }

  if (isset($path) && (in_array($node->attributes('id'), $path) || in_array($node->attributes('rel'), $path)))
  {
    if ($node->attributes('class')) {
      $node->addAttribute('class', $node->attributes('class').' active');
    } else {
      $node->addAttribute('class', 'active');
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (isset($args['children']) && !$args['children'])
    {
      $children = $node->children();
      foreach ($node->children() as $child)
      {
        if ($child->name() == 'ul') {
          $node->removeChild($child);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (($node->name() == 'li') && ($id = $node->attributes('id'))) {
    if ($node->attributes('class')) {
      $node->addAttribute('class', $node->attributes('class').' item'.$id);
    } else {
      $node->addAttribute('class', 'item'.$id);
    }
  }

  if (isset($path) && $node->attributes('id') == $path[0]) {
    $node->addAttribute('id', 'current');
  } else {
    $node->removeAttribute('id');
  }
  $node->removeAttribute('rel');
  $node->removeAttribute('level');
  $node->removeAttribute('access');
}
  define('modMainMenuXMLCallbackDefined', true);
}
ob_start();

modMainMenuHelper::render($params, 'modMyMainMenuXMLCallback');
$menu_html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 

if($params->get('menutype')=="mainmenu"){
  $tag = $params->get('tag_id');
}

//output the menu!
echo fancyMenuPatch($menu_html,$tag);
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the code in the override file? The active menu ID and class are set in the core template file, if you are overriding it then you will need to account for that.

Comment: Thanks, Brent. I'll post the code tomorrow; don't have access to it now.

Comment: the menu structure doesn't seems to be generated by mod_mainmenu. Check once again, this might be generated by other menu module.

Comment: @Prakash, thanks for your reply. It is using the mod_mainmenu, because I'm generating that output using the override. However, I'm not sure why the `active`/`current` attributes aren't being set. The final result shouldn't have the `access` and `level` attributes.

Comment: I'm using the example from here: http://www.fatica.net/blog/69-overriding-joomla-default-modmainmenu-output.html At the bottom of the code there, it checks the `menutype` to be equal to `primarynav` to set the `$tag`. In my case, I discovered that I wasn't using that menutype but `mainmenu`. Could that be causing the issue? What is `primarynav`? Couldn't find anything on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, here's code for mod_mainmenu (override):

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

if ( ! defined('fancyMenuPatch') ) 
{
  function fancyMenuPatch($result,$tag){
    $menu   = JSite::getMenu();
    $active = $menu->getActive();

    // Add to the start of the UL tag.
    $begin_ul = "<ul id=\"top-nav\" class=\"flatList\">";
    $begin_span = "<span class=\"embed embed-top-nav\">";

    $home_p = "Home</span><p>news, highlights</p></a>";
    $watch_p = "Watch UNC-TV</span><p>schedule, programs</p></a>";
    $learn_p = "Learn</span><p>education, unc-tv kids</p></a>";
    $support_p = "Support Us</span><p>pledge, volunteer, corporate</p></a>";
    $contact_p = "Contact</span><p>feedback, connect, share</p></a>";

    // do the replacements
    $result = str_replace("<ul class=\"menu\">",$begin_ul, $result);
    $result = str_replace("<span>", $begin_span, $result);
    $result = str_replace("Home</span></a>",$home_p,$result);
    $result = str_replace("Watch UNC-TV</span></a>",$watch_p,$result);
    $result = str_replace("Learn</span></a>",$learn_p,$result);
    $result = str_replace("Support Us</span></a>",$support_p,$result);
    $result = str_replace("Contact</span></a>",$contact_p,$result);

    return $result;
  }
  define('fancyMenuPatch', true);
}

if ( ! defined('modMyMainMenuXMLCallbackDefined') )

  {

  function modMyMainMenuXMLCallback(&$node, $args)

  {

  $user  = &JFactory::getUser();

  $menu  = &JSite::getMenu();

  $active  = $menu->getActive();

  $path  = isset($active) ? array_reverse($active->tree) : null; if (($args['end']) && ($node->attributes('level') >= $args['end']))
  {

  $children = $node->children();

  foreach ($node->children() as $child)

  {

  if ($child->name() == 'ul') {

  $node->removeChild($child);

  }

  }

  }

 if ($node->name() == 'ul') {

  foreach ($node->children() as $child)

  {

  if ($child->attributes('access') > $user->get('aid', 0)) {

  $node->removeChild($child);

  }

  }

  }

 if (($node->name() == 'li') && isset($node->ul)) {

  $node->addAttribute('class', 'parent');

  }

 if (isset($path) && in_array($node->attributes('id'), $path))

  {

  if ($node->attributes('class')) {

  $node->addAttribute('class', $node->attributes('class').' active');

  } else {

  $node->addAttribute('class', 'active');

  }

  }

  else

  {

  if (isset($args['children']) && !$args['children'])

  {

  $children = $node->children();

  foreach ($node->children() as $child)

  {

  if ($child->name() == 'ul') {

  $node->removeChild($child);

  }

  }

  }

  }

 if (($node->name() == 'li') && ($id = $node->attributes('id'))) {

  if ($node->attributes('class')) {

  $node->addAttribute('class', $node->attributes('class').' item'.$id);

  } else {

  $node->addAttribute('class', 'item'.$id);

  }

  }

 if (isset($path) && $node->attributes('id') == $path[0]) {

  $node->addAttribute('id', 'current');

  } else {

  $node->removeAttribute('id');

  }

  $node->removeAttribute('level');

  $node->removeAttribute('access');



  }

  define('modMyMainMenuXMLCallbackDefined', true);

}

ob_start();

modMainMenuHelper::render($params, 'modMyMainMenuXMLCallback');
$menu_html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 

if($params->get('menutype')=="mainmenu"){
  $tag = $params->get('tag_id');
}

//output the menu!
echo fancyMenuPatch($menu_html,$tag);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Prakash. This works! But why? What was wrong with my mod_mainmenu override?

Comment: Do'h!! I see the error of my ways: I spelled the mod function as `modMainMenuXMLCallback` and then render it by calling `modMyMainMenuXMLCallback`. Dang.

Answer (score 1):

Check your template folder, there is a template.css file, you can find there !

Comment: I'm using a custom template that has no template.css file.