# Creating a secondary menu in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I've used this technique to override the mod_mainmenu in Joomla 1.5: [Highlight active menu item in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198002/highlight-active-menu-item-in-joomla)

Now I've discovered that all the menus created in Joomla are based off of mod_mainmenu. Now I'd like to create a secondary menu for some of the pages based on this accordion design: http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla/Accordion-Menu-Apple-style.php#demo

Is it possible to have both of those designs in Joomla for menu types or am I stuck with the override version only? Any options? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new module called `mod_secondarymenu` with you design, js and css.

Copy `mod_mainmenu` and overwrite code as needed. Then in the module manager change the module type from `mod_mainmenu` to your `mod_secondarymenu`.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. That sounds relatively simple. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: A follow-up: In Module Manager, how do you change the module type? I was just looking at that and wasn't sure how it's done. Thanks.

Comment: oh... you will have to remove old module and add new one. Your new module should be in the list of modules if you installed it. If not you might need to insert a record for new module in `jos_modules` table.